# What proof of negative test do I need before travelling to Belgium from UK?

Tags: covid-19, belgium, eurostar

I'm travelling to Belgium next week from the UK on the Eurostar. According to the [current guidelines](https://www.info-coronavirus.be/en/travels/), I need to have a negative RAT (lateral flow test) on the day of travel, but where is this checked, and what proof do I need?

Is the text/email (example below) from the NHS enough, or do I need the physical test, or something else?

The rest of the testing requirements are clear enough as PCR tests are done at Belgian test centres.

[image: NHS Covid testing result text]

Comment: Have you checked this site to see if your question can be answered? [Coronavirus and Eurostar Services | Travel News | Eurostar](https://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-info/service-information/coronavirus-and-eurostar-service)

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I have. It says exactly the same as the official guidelines I linked.

Comment: NHS tests (unlike the vaccination certificates) are not valid for travel and never have been. I can generate an email as the one above by picking up a (free) NHS test at a pharmacy, typing in the code on the test and tick "test was negative", I don't ever have to take the test.

Answer (score 1):

**While this answer was likely right when posted it may well be out of date now.**

According to the official [FAQ](https://www.info-coronavirus.be/en/faq/#id_7), you should provide a test certificate. If the certificate is attached to the e-mail (e.g., a PDF-file), it should be fine. Usually, this is checked at the departure airport (e.g., at the airport counter check-in) and they might also check the certificate upon arrival.

Comment: He asked about Eurostar. Departure is a bit like an airport but still different.

Comment: I suppose that one may additionally be checked while in Belgium.In fact, if I interpret the circumstance correctly (entry of non-resident from a "red" non-EU/non-Schengen country): You have to 1) make a **PCR or RAT** test no more than 72 or 36 hours before arrival; obviously, this test result must be certified and linked to your ID (in whatever way this is done in home country). 2) Make a **PCR test on day one** in Belgium 3) make another **PCR test on day 7** in Belgium. 4) Stay **quarantined** until you have the (negative, of course) result from the day 1 (vaxed) or day 7 (non-vaxed) test.

Comment: I've never done a Covid test that came with any kind of certificate, in the UK the ones I've had just send you a text and email with the result. There's no official markings, certification or QR code like the vaccine pass.

Comment: Updated the question with the test result I'm used to receiving

Comment: @Mourndark NHS tests are not supposed to be used for international travel and lacks the exact time of collection, you may need to find a private provider.

Comment: @Mourndark I have googled 'covid test rapid with travel certificate UK' and got this https://www.c19testing.co.uk/rapidtravel/ as a first link. They say they provide travel certificates with QR code.

Comment: @xngtng in fact https://www.gov.uk/guidance/nhs-covid-pass#how-to-use-the-nhs-covid-pass-when-travelling-abroad claims that one can show the vaccination records in your NHS COVID Pass as proof of your COVID-19 status when travelling abroad (in the NHS App as I understand) but every country would rather follow their own requirements

Comment: @xngtng Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for!